# How to export all MobileConnect SMS subscriptions? [Solved]

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms, unsubscriber

I simply want to have an automated daily export of our SMS opt outs to our ftp.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done under Automation Studio:

1. Create a DE to store the unsubscribers

   -- SubscriptionID,MobileNumber,OptOutStatusID,OptOutDate
2. SQL Query:

SELECT _MobileSubscriptionID AS SubscriptionID, 
       _MobileNumber AS MobileNumber, 
       _OptOutStatusID AS OptOutStatusID, 
       _OptOutDate AS OptOutDate 
FROM _MobileSubscription
WHERE _OptOutStatusID = 1

3. Data Extract
4. File Transfer